# Interactively Manipulate Code

Tags: dynamic, interactive

Bear with me, I'm a noob; I simply want to create a radio button bar that selects whether I want to add or subtract two numbers:

```
{RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[stringvar], {"*" -> "Multiply Numbers", "+" -> "Add Numbers"}]}
```

And my equation might simply be:

```
2 + 2
```

And I just want to change the + to a * interactively. Not sure if this is the right way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Create a Dynamic variable that is the `Head` of an expression, and can take the values `Plus` or `Times`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
Manipulate[operator[x, y], 
 {{x, 2}, InputField}, 
 {{y, 2}, InputField}, 
 {operator, {Plus, Times, Subtract, Divide}}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Column[
 {Row[{InputField[Dynamic[x]], InputField[Dynamic[y]]}],
  RadioButtonBar[
   Dynamic[op], {Times -> "Multiply Numbers", 
    Plus -> "Add Numbers"}],
  Dynamic@op[x, y]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Notice how code and data are the same thing in Mathematica, so I can use the fact that the operators `Plus` and `Times` can be stored in variables to construct the interface.

You can also use arbitrary dynamic controls here

```
Column[
 {Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x]], InputField[Dynamic[y]]},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]],
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[op], {Plus, Times, Subtract, Divide}],
  Dynamic@op[x, y]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: you're quick today, I just copied mine :)

Comment: I just happened to come here when the question was asked :)